# How do I use a coroutine a a closure?

Tags: python, async-await, closures, coroutine

I'm making a Discord bot that plays music and found the following code online (which has been modified by me):

```
async def play(self, inter: disnake.CmdInter, url):
    """Plays a song from a given YouTube URL."""

    async with inter.channel.typing():
        self.queue.append([inter.channel, url])
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(
            url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True
        )
        try:
            self.bot.voice_clients[0].play(
                player,
                after=...
            )
        except disnake.errors.ClientException:  # Already playing a song
            self.queue.append([inter.channel, url])
            await inter.send(
                f"Added `{player.title}` to queue "
                f"(Nr. {self.queue.index([inter.channel, url]) + 1})"
            )
            return
    await inter.send(f"Now playing: `{player.title}`")
```

The `after` kwarg allows me to specify a closure that is executed after the playback stops. To add a queue system, I wanted to have `after` lead to a function that recursively plays the next song in the queue until the queue is empty.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to use closures of coroutines (which the recursive function has to be since the playback requires the use of coroutines). `after=await foo`, `after=foo`, `after=lambda: await foo`, `after=lambda: foo` and some more combinations don't work and I haven't found anything about coroutine closures on the internet.

Maybe they just don't work like that, I'm not familiar with asynchronous programming, so I wouldn't know.

Comment: It's unclear. You need to provide a [mre] and debugging details. Are you using 'discord.py'? Then see [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/async/faq.html#how-do-i-pass-a-coroutine-to-the-player-s-after-function).

Comment: @relent95 I'm using Disnake, but nonetheless, the article you linked seems like it solves my problem, I'll try it out later.